# Relative compactness in $L^2(0,T,BD(\Omega))$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Here is the hypothesis of my problem : $T>0$, $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a regular boundary and I have a sequence of functions $(v_n)_n$ such that 
$$\forall n \in\mathbb{N}, v_n\in L^2(0,T,BD(\Omega)) $$
where $BD(\Omega)$ is the space of functions of bounded deformations. Furthermore, the sequence $(v_n)_n$ is supposed to be bounded in $L^2(0,T,BD(\Omega)) $. I know that I can find a subsequence of $(v_n)_n$ that converges weak-* in $L^2_{\text{weak}}(0,T;BD(\Omega))$ (the index weak means that we use the weak measurability) but I'm not sure what it actually means. Can somebody help me to understand what it means ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that (if we denote by $(v_n)_n$ the subsequence of $(v_n)_n$) there exists $v\in L^2_{\text{weak}}(0,T;BD(\Omega))$ such that for all $\phi\in L^2(0,T;C)$ we have $\int_0^T \left(v_n,\phi\right)_{BD(\Omega),C}(t)\text{d}t \to \int_0^T (v,\phi)_{BD(\Omega),C}(t)\text{d}t$.

Am I right ? Or do I miss something ?